# Missing cookie \"access_token_cookie\ Python Flask

Tags: python, json, flask, cookies, jwt

I have a login function to authenticate the users of my APIs using JWT and have set access and refresh cookies once the user has logged in as per the below code:

**login code**

```
@flask_app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():

    email = request.json.get('email')
    password = request.json.get('password', None).encode('UTF-8')

    #print(email)
    #print(password)

    if not email:
        return('Missing email', 400)
    if not password:
        return('Missing password', 400)
    
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.email == email).first() or None
    if user is None:
        return('Wrong email or password!'), 400

    hashed_password = bcrypt.checkpw(base64.b64encode(sha256(password).digest()), user.hashed_password)
    if hashed_password:
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id)
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=user.id)
        permissions = get_user_permissions(user.id)
        resp = jsonify({'email': user.email, 'permissions': permissions})
        set_access_cookies(resp, access_token)
        set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
        return resp
```

When I login I can see the access and refresh cookies in the postman headers section so it is logging in the user correctly.
[image: Postman Cookies]

When I navigate to a route that requires a jwt token I get the error below and cannot see the access token cookie in Postman.

```
Missing cookie \"access_token_cookie\
```

**jwt_required code snippet**

```
@flask_app.route('/device-data/<unit_id>', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def get_data(unit_id):
    find_device = db.session.query(Unit).filter(Unit.id == unit_id).first()
```

**jwt config**

```
jwt = JWTManager(flask_app)
flask_app.config['JWT_CSRF_CHECK_FORM'] = True
flask_app.config['JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION'] = ['cookies']
flask_app.config['JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT'] = True
flask_app.config['JWT_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
flask_app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'Super Secret'
flask_app.config['JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES'] = timedelta(minutes=120)
flask_app.config['JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES'] = timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Have you found anything useful about this? I'm facing a very similar issue currently, except I don't even get the `Set-Cookie` headers

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/token_locations/#cookies) this is likely because you have set your app so cookies containing your JWT can only be sent over https but your app is running locally in development on http. For testing your app (do not do this in development!) you can configure your app like this:

`app.config["JWT_COOKIE_SECURE"] = False`